# Regex Validação de telefone

Tags: regex

Atualmente estou usando uma expressão regular para validar telefones no seguinte formato:

> (xx) xxxxx-xxxx

Ela aceita apenas números que tenham esse exato formato. Gostaria de saber como modificar a expressão para aceitar números tanto com 9 dígitos (celulares), tanto com 8 (fixo), algo como:

> (xx) [x]xxxx-xxxx

Segue a expressão.

```
/^\([0-9]{2}\) [0-9]{5}-[0-9]{4}$/
```

Comment: Altere para `\([0-9]{2}\) [0-9]{4,5}-[0-9]{4}` somente a parte de `[0-9]{5}` para `[0-9]{4,5}` que ao invés de aceitar 5 dígitos, irá aceitar de 4 a 5 dígitos. Porém, como celulares estão iniciando com o número 9, você pode fazer `\([0-9]{2}\) 9?[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}`, em que o quantificador `?` corresponde a zero ou um do número 9 literal. Veja a [demo aqui](https://regex101.com/r/zUH2AX/3). Infelizmente deste modo irá validar celulares com 8 dígitos, portanto altere para `\([0-9]{2}\) (?:9[0-9]{1}|[1-5]{1})[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}` e a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zUH2AX/4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte Regex:

```
/^\([0-9]{2}\) [0-9]?[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$/
```